# "pip install" broken on Python for Windows when installing opts module

Tags: windows, python, pip

I'm getting errors chain when I try to install [opts](https://pypi.org/project/opts/) on Python's own `pip` script at `Python34` folder. Somehow it can't manage to install.

Trying opts:

```
----------------------------------->>>
Downloading/unpacking opts
  Downloading opts-0.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\opts\setup.py) egg_info for package opts
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\opts\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
    ImportError: No module named 'distribute_setup'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\opts\setup.py", line 3, in <module>

    from distribute_setup import use_setuptools

ImportError: No module named 'distribute_setup'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user\opts
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log
```

Me trying to install `distribute_setup`:

```
 ---------->

C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install distribute_setup
Downloading/unpacking distribute-setup
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement distribute-setup
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for distribute-setup
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log
```

The pip.log file:

```
 ---------->
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip run on 08/17/19 02:17:45
Downloading/unpacking distribute-setup
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/ when looking for download links for distribute-setup
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for distribute-setup:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute_setup/ when looking for download links for distribute-setup
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement distribute-setup
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_user...
No distributions at all found for distribute-setup
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for distribute-setup
```

Answer (score 1):

> `pip install` is somehow broken[.]

This seems unlikely.

I get the same errors in both Python 2.7.16 and Python 3.x with relatively current versions of `pip` (`pip` version 18.x and `pip` version 19.x. respectively). And `pip` works normally otherwise for me.

What seems more likely is that `opts` is an old module and is using outdated references and instructions in its scripts, which are causing errors.

Regarding age, consider that [opts was released in 2010](https://pypi.org/project/opts/#history), [along with Python 2.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_release_dates) and that currently [official support for Python 2.7 is scheduled to end in January 2020](https://pythonclock.org/).

---

*As a suggestion, if this isn't merely a support module for an existing script, you should look into possibly using something other than `opts`. One option might be Python's own [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.*

---